# I am smelly, but beautiful, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Tell me… What am I?

> I am the biggest. 
>   I am the rarest.
>   I am the strangest.
>   I am bodiless.
>
> I am smelly. 
>   But beauty.

Comment: I think it is farting

Comment: "Smelly but beautiful" A riddle... about me? Why... I'm honored.

Comment: not really on topic, but I saw this question on "hot network questions" while listening to Roses, by OutKast ... "_See that roses really smell like poo-poo-oo_"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to guess..

> [Rafflesia arnoldii?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafflesia_arnoldii) (aka corpse flower)

I am the biggest.

> it is the biggest flower in the world

I am the rarest.

> Not sure about 'rarest' but it is definitely rare, one of the rarest flowers in indonesia (not sure if it exists anywhere else).

I am the strangest.

> It's massive and it smells like corpses. Sounds like a strange flower to me.

I am bodiless.

> Flowers don't have body, i guess. Heck, it doesnt even look like it has a body/stalk at all - it looks just like a big flower on the ground.

I am smelly.

> It's called the corpse flower so that should give an idea on how smelly it is

But beauty.

> It is quite the sight to behold.

Comment: Im not sure how beautiful it is but it seems you are correct

Answer (score 2):

Ambergris

I am the biggest. - Usually comes in large chunks

I am the rarest. - Very rare and very expensive

I am the strangest. - Whale excretions are pretty strange?

I am bodiless. - comes form a whales body, but is just a chunk

I am smelly. - usually smells like fecal matter when first produced

But beauty. - Used in the most expensive of perfumes

Answer (score 0):

I would say a dug up and emptied war cemetery

I am the biggest

> Lots of soldiers (were there), need lots of ground

I am the strangest

> Why does a cemetery have no bodies?

I am bodiless

> The bodies are gone

I am the rarest

> Who digs up a military cemetery?

I am smelly

> The smell of dug up rotting flesh

I am beautiful

> Generally the grounds of graveyards are well kept and organised, so if a professional did this he/she/they would probably put it back in its original state, just without the bodies